# How to read data from XML using simplexml_load_string

Tags: php, arrays, xml, simplexml

I want to display some data from my XML. This is my XML:

```
[@attributes] => Array (
[id] => 2065 )
[price] => Array (
    [@attributes] => Array (
    [gross] => 1259.16
    [net] => 1023.71
    [vat] => 23.0 )
    )
[srp] => Array (
    [@attributes] => Array (
    [gross] => 1499.00
    [net] => 1218.7
    [vat] => 23.0 )
    )
[sizes] => Array (
    [size] => Array (
        [@attributes] => Array (
        [id] => 0
        [code_producer] => 33124.16.EN
        [code] => 2065-0
        [weight] => 999 )
        [stock] => Array (
            [@attributes] => Array (
            [id] => 1
            [quantity] => 1
            )
        )
    )
```

I want to get value from:

- [id] => 2065,
- [price][net] => 1023.71,
- [sizes][size][stock][quantity] => 1.

After reading the following comments, I modified my code. However, I still can not, I do not understand how to get attribute values.

```
foreach ($xmlArray AS $produkt) {
        foreach ($produkt AS $abc) {
            foreach ($abc AS $singleValue) {

                $data[] = array('net' => (string)$singleValue->price['net']);
            }
        }
    }
    return $data;
```

And the output: `Array ( [0] => Array ( [net] => b ) [1] => Array ( [net] => ) [2] => Array ( [net] => ) ) 1`

The problem is, I don't know how many times I should use foreach and this param @attributes is strange for me. thanks for help.

Kind regards

Comment: Please include the original XML (not the result of outputting a processed document)  - it's much easier to work with.

Answer (score 0):

SimpleXML doesn't produce an array, it produces an object. Please check the [basic examples in the manual](http://php.net/manual/en/simplexml.examples-basic.php) for how to use it.

The `@attributes` in your debug output is just to separate child attributes from elements, it's not actually how you access them.

Looking at your debug output, it looks like what you actually want is something like this:

```
foreach ( $xml_object->products->product as $product ) {
     $data[] = array('net' => (string)$product->price['net']);
     $data[] = array('net' => (string)$product->srp['net']);
}
```